# field appears null or empty sting but I can not select it

Tags: postgresql

```
select *
from ss.mailer_data
where
id = 249122
and address_3 like'%%'
```

will not hit on address_3.  I've tried changing the last line to

```
and address_3 is null
```

`and address_3 = ''`

`and address_3 = ' '`

I tried using char_length, ascii functions and they return nothing for that filed value.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could also be that `id = 249122` is not true for that combination. What happens when you do

```
select *
from ss.mailer_data
where address_3 is null
```

or

```
select *
from ss.mailer_data
where address_3 = ''
```

Comment: ya know i hit on = null when i did it that way.  i changed the order of the where clause and now it's hitting but that should not have been an issue (i think..).  My sanity is slipping  ;)  thanks

Answer (score 0):

NULL is a special case - It's undefined but if that were your problem, Is Null should've found it

Can I ask you what data IS actually stored in Address3?

If you just want all records where address3 is empty/null,

```
select *
from ss.mailer_data
where
RTRIM(COALESCE(address_3, '')) =''
```

NB: LIKE is computationally expensive so use it carefully. Also, like '%%' is identical to Like '%'

Are you sure you had the right Id?